# HTML: Replace a rectangle in specified location of an image

Tags: html, image, canvas

I displayed an image on my HTML page.
Upon clicking a specified area in the image:

Xmin < MouseLocation.x < Xmax &&
Ymin < MouseLocation.y < Ymax

I want to replace this area **only** with another small image.

What is the right way to do it ?

Should I place canvas on the image and upon clicking the canvas, load image to it ?

The goal is to change switch states displayed in the attached file.

Thank you,
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

```js
const EG = document.getElementById("EG");

const ctx = EG.getContext("2d")

EG.addEventListener("click", ({offsetX, offsetY}) => {
  ctx.fillRect(offsetX, offsetY, 4, 4);
  // use ctx.drawImage instead
})
```

```css
canvas {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="EG"></canvas>
```